# How to update ClamAV virus definitions?

Tags: updates, clamav

What should I do in order to update anti-virus definitions and GUI version for ClamAV? I tried updating all my software, but that made no difference.

Comment: There is no GUI for ClamAV, are you perhaps referring to third-party GUI software such as ClamTk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update ClamAV definitions database?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/114000/how-to-update-clamav-definitions-database)

Answer (score 1):

Most distributions run the update command automatically, but if you want to manually update the ClamAV definitions, then run this command in a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo freshclam
```

If you are referring to ClamTk when you say its GUI, then you can download the latest `.deb` file which will upgrade it for you from here: https://code.google.com/p/clamtk/

Comment: If the daemon is running to update the definitions automatically, there will be an error about the logs being locked. See comments at (duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/q/114000/17060