# I can't update the clamav antivirus

Tags: security, antivirus, clamav

I was updating the clamav antivirus defenitons with the `sudo freshclam` command and the output was:

```
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/114000/how-to-update-clamav-definitions-database

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is likely to be because the update is currently being run automatically, or you are running it somewhere else (you would know about this). You can change how often it is run automatically, and also stop it being run automatically by running the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

After completing the setup you will be able to run `sudo freshclam` without error (unless you set it to `cron` and you happen to execute the command at the time it automatically checks).

Comment: You are correct, this error is because the daemon is running.  +1 for beating me to the answer.  =)  By the way, after completing the setup, it will let you run the `sudo freshclam`.

Comment: @Terrance: I'm sure I've also seen this question asked before (I think I may have even answered it), but I can't find it to mark as duplicate...

Comment: I know I have answered it too once before.  =)  I'll take a look.

Comment: You actually asked it:  http://askubuntu.com/q/636851/231142

Comment: @Terrance: Oh, how funny! :D

Comment: I was having the same issue in Ubuntu 16.04 after a fresh install of `clamav` (without the daemon) and a reboot. Reconfiguring `clamav-freshclam`, as suggested, fixed the issue.

Comment: I need to use this suggestion as well. Needed. http://askubuntu.com/questions/526317/cant-run-freshclam

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that you cannot update *clamav* database due to it being locked by running daemon. Presumably Ubuntu proceeds with an automatic update.

**To update virus database manually, you have to stop daemon by typing in CLI:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop
```

Now you can update virus signatures:

```
sudo freshclam -v
```

Finally, restart daemon with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start
```

Comment: You'd be better off just setting it to `cron` in the configuration, why set it to `deamon` if you don't want it all the time?

Comment: I don't value what's better. I answered the question.

Comment: `sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam` then `sudo freshclam` then `sudo systemctl start clamav-freshclam`

Answer (score -2):

Another thing to do is to edit the /var/log/clamav/freshclam. conf file and change the 1 to 0. This is the only datavthat you will see in the file,  if not LEAVE IT ALONE!!!!!!  and wait.

Do this ONLY IF THE OTHER  SOLUTIONS  DO NOT WORK! 
While this is a drastic step, what it does is to tell Freshclam that it hasn't run yet.

REMEMBER THIS IS ONLY THE FINAL SOLUTION if the other  suggestions  do not work.

Comment: No need to shout :)